# Dynamic inputfield increase number +1 in variable

Tags: javascript

I have this function to be able to dynamicly add inputfields.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('focus', 'div.input-group-option:last-child input', function(){
      var sInputGroupHtml = $('div.input-group-option:last-child').html();

      var sInputGroupClasses = $('div.input-group-option').attr('class');

      $('div.input-group-option').parent().append(`<div class="${sInputGroupClasses}">${sInputGroupHtml}</div>`);

    });
});
```

I am using this function as below, starting with 3 visible inputfields:

```
<div class="input-group-option-container">';
    for($x = 0; $x <= 2; $x++) { echo '
    <div class="input-group-option">

        <div class="col-md-1">';
            if($x == 0) { echo '<label for="add_aantal_div['.$x.']">Aantal</label>'; } echo '
            <div class="form-group" id="add_aantal_div['.$x.']">
                <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="add_aantal['.$x.']" name="add_aantal[]" value="">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>'; } echo '
</div>
```

When I view the generated code I find:

```
<div class="input-group-option-container">
    <div class="input-group-option">

        <div class="col-md-1"><label for="add_aantal_div[0]">Aantal</label>
            <div class="form-group" id="add_aantal_div[0]">
                <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="add_aantal[0]" name="add_aantal[]" value="">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="input-group-option">

        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="form-group" id="add_aantal_div[1]">
                <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="add_aantal[1]" name="add_aantal[]" value="">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="input-group-option">

        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="form-group" id="add_aantal_div[2]">
                <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="add_aantal[2]" name="add_aantal[]" value="">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

But now when an extra inputfield is added by focussing the last row of file above it is shown as:

```
<div class="input-group-option">

    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="form-group" id="add_aantal_div[2]">
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="add_aantal[2]" name="add_aantal[]" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Notice, again with variable 2.
How to make sure to have this varibled raised by 1 each time an inputfield is dynamicly added?

[image]

Comment: Count `div.input-group-option`, this will be the index.

Comment: That might be an solution, but how to change the varible between the `[]` since the name of the `id` will be different for other inputfield in the same form?

Comment: Find `input` in `sInputGroupHtml` and set id attribute there.

Comment: What exactly do you need these IDs for in the first place? (If this is for client-side scripting purposes - elements can be selected in a multitude of ways, it doesn’t always have to be by ID. Making use of the relation of elements to each other in the DOM structure for example is often a better way to go about such things, than nailing IDs onto every single element that didn’t run away fast enough …)

Comment: `parent().append()`, I am pretty sure that parent can tell you how many children it has already. That is the number you need.